# How to save charts in same pdf file using Xchart and VectorGraphics2D

Tags: java, itext

I create chart using Xchart and save it as PDF file using VectorGraphics2D as follows:

```
VectorGraphicsEncoder.saveVectorGraphic(chart, "chart_name", VectorGraphicsFormat.PDF);
```

However I need to save several charts in the same PDF file. Is there any way of doing it using iText?

```
ProcessingPipeline g = null;
g = new PDFGraphics2D(0.0, 0.0, chart.getWidth(), chart.getHeight());
chart.paint(g, chart.getWidth(), chart.getHeight());
FileOutputStream file1 = new FileOutputStream(addFileExtension("doc_name", VectorGraphicsFormat.PDF));
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, file1);
doc.open();
```

However I fail when I add the `g` to the document. How do I fix this?

Comment: You fail. In what way do you fail? Do you get an error?

Comment: When I do doc.add(g) it appears that we can only insert Element type to the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can save an image with desired grid in one image using :

```
BitmapEncoder.saveBitmap(
            Arrays.asList(new Chart[]{chart1, chart2, chart3, chart4}), 2,2, "./cumulative", BitmapEncoder.BitmapFormat.PNG);
```

where 2,2 is the row and col size.
After getting this image with 4 charts you can export it in a PDF.